# Filling an array with a string on a side function. Why does it prints gibberish?

Tags: c, arrays

I can't find help about this. Most issues i found are related to not closing the array with a '\0' , but this is not the case.

```
void main() {
    char text[1000];
    int index=0;
    loadText(text,&index);
    printf("\nThe text is:\n %s",text);
    getch();
}

void loadText(char* text,int* index){
    printf("Insert the text: \n");
    while((*index<1000) && (text[*index]=getchar())!=EOF) {
        *index++;
    }
    text[*index]='\0';
}
```

When i print the array it shows random chars.

On a side note, this is a test and we are forced to write the function as:

```
void  loadText(char*, int*)
```

Comment: `int ch; for(*index = 0; *index<1000-1 && (ch=getchar())!=EOF; ++*index) { text[*index] = ch; }`

Comment: when posting a question of the form: why does my code not work,  post code that cleanly compiles.   The posted code does not compile (missing the necessary `#include` statement(s)

Comment: the function: `getch()` is non standard suggest: `int ch; while( (ch=getchar()) != EOF ) ;  getchar();`

Comment: there are only a couple valid signatures for the `main()` function and the ALL have a return type of `int`, not `void`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
*index++;
```

doesn't increment the the value in the pointer. Instead it gets the value ie `(*index)` and then increment the pointer itself `(index=index+1)`.

Do

```
(*index)++;
```